# Some icons in inbox/achievements are wrong, only on chat

Tags: bug, design, notifications, top-bar

Today I'm seeing the wrong icon in the dropdowns *only on chat*.  The circled icons should be Writers, not Worldbuilding:

[image: chat screen shot]

They're correct on the Q&A sites:

[image: Writers screen shot]

I've only seen this for Writers so far.  If I get any inbox notifications or rep for other late-in-the-alphabet sites, I'll update.  As you can see in the screen shot from chat, Meta.SE is fine.

I suspect this has to do with the creation of new sites, indexing, and caching, but new-site is Tuesday and it's Thursday now, so that's some pretty heavy-duty caching if that's the cause.

Comment: Probably an off-by-one error

Comment: See also [TL transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/4?m=42470376#42470376).

Comment: Caching duration is on the order of days there, so this isn't entirely abnormal. Should fix itself.

Comment: @AdamLear oh, I didn't realize caching could be *that* long.  Thanks for the information.