# Wrong icon on chat reply notifications on chat server

Tags: bug, chat, design, notifications

When looking at chat replies on a regular SE site, I see this:

[image: correct icon]

However, when looking at the same notification on [chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com), I see this:

[image: wrong icon]

As you can see from the hovertext, it seems to just be the icon that is being loaded incorrectly: the [SQA.meta.SE](https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com/) icon is being loaded instead of the SE icon.

This [seems to have happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306224/307833), but with no real resolution other than "wait and it might go away".

Comment: Probably the same favicon bug as always when a [new beta site](https://neo.stackexchange.com) launches...

Comment: "happened before" was only a week ago

Comment: @Cai Oh, whoops, I misread the date - I thought it was a year ago! I'll close this as a dupe, then.